# Can't install Flask in Enthought Canopy on OSX Mavericks

Tags: enthought

I am trying to use the Package Manager to install Flask. Two versions are displayed, I get the following errors:

> Action: install flask-0.10.1-2.egg
>   The package manager has encountered error
>   HTTP Error 404: NOT FOUND: https://api.enthought.com/eggs/osx-64/flask-0.10.1-2.egg

--

> Action: install flask-0.10.1-1.egg
>   The package manager has encountered error
>   HTTP Error 404: NOT FOUND: https://api.enthought.com/eggs/osx-64/Jinja2-2.6-2.egg

Thanks in advance, for any help on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is a server error affecting access for free users. We will fix it ASAP.